# Pandas dataframe with multiple hierarchical indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
FRUIT       ID      COLOR       WEIGHT
Apple       142     Red         Heavy
Mango       231     Red         Light
Apple       764     Green       Light
Apple       543     Green       Heavy
```

And I want the following result:

```
FRUIT                 COUNT
Apple       COLOR
            Red         1
            Green       2

            WEIGHT
            Heavy       2
            Light       1

Mango       COLOR
            Red         1
            Green       0
            
            WEIGHT
            Heavy       0
            Light       1
```

I tried different variations of `set_index`, `groupby()` and `unstack()` on the dataframe in combination with `['ID]'.count()` and `.size()`, but my grouping works only on the first level (Fruit).
On the second level I am not able to get color and weight separately, I always end up with weight as another subindex of color so it looks like

```
FRUIT                 
Apple       COLOR    WEIGHT   COUNT
            Red      Heavy    1
                     Light    0

            Green    Heavy    1
                     Light    1
```

How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working with below simple line of code

```
df.set_index('fruit').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts().unstack(level=[1,2]).fillna(0)
```